# Is this modulo operation safe?

Tags: c++, modulo

```
int a = 978;
int b = 24;
int c = a - (a / b) * b;
```

`c` seems to be remainder of division of `a` and `b` but i don't believe that `operator %` is doing exactly the same. So what's the trick?

Comment: Please elaborate why you think they are different.

Comment: @inneedofhelp I thought it was too easy and there is gotta be some pitfall)

Comment: @Ivars, I share your point of view. good to know **why** these operations will be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator does actually do exactly that. Your method is safe as long as `b != 0`, but the same thing goes when using `%`.

Answer (score 0):

a - (a/b) * b = a % b

c=a%b calculates the remainder of a when divided by b and is stored in c.